# SQL query with table structure

Tags: sql, join, database-design

I have a database table structure as follow:

```
datatype
data
mytable
```

now datatype has primary key datatypeid, data table has datatypeid as foriegn key and has mytable id as foreign key.

In datatype I have a column called description which has address1, address2 etc

And the values for these addresses are stored in data table using the datatypeid as reference.

So I want to make a select statement to show the ids from mytable and address1, address2 etc as columns, with the values coming from `data.values` as follow:

```
id address1  address2
1  test add  test add2
2  test add  test add2
2  test add  test add2
```

here is my query so far but it outputs it in different format:

```
SELECT     id
FROM       datatype 
INNER JOIN data ON datatype.DataTypeID = data.DataTypeID 
INNER JOIN mytable ON data.ID = mytable.ID
```

**EDIT :**
table structure:

```
datatype 
  -datatypeid int
  -description varchar(50)
data
  -id int
  -datatypeid int
  -datavalue varchar(50)
  -mytableid int
mytable
  -mytableid int
  -datecreated datetime
```

**Sample Data**

```
datatype :
datatypeid  description
1           address1
2           address2

data :
id datatypeid datavalue        mytableid
1   1         george street     1

mytable:
mytableid datecreated
1         2012-02-17 10:06:02.507
```

Can you help please?

Comment: That was totally unclear. Please show the struture of the tables involved and some sample data.

Comment: if I am understanding it correctly, you want all the descriptions from datatype to become the column names for this query and then the data for this query comes from the data table. is this correct?

Comment: if there were a static number of rows in datatype i could help you out (you could use case statements to fill in the columns). however if the number of rows in datatype are going to be dynamic I can't think of a good way to set that row data up as columns

Comment: @peroija datatype table is static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spitballing this, but give it a try

```
SELECT m.mytableid, CASE WHEN dt.datatypeid = 1 AND d.datatypeid =1 THEN d.datavalue ELSE null END AS "address1"
    , CASE WHEN dt.datatypeid = 2 AND d.datatypeid =2 THEN d.datavalue ELSE null END AS "address2"
    ,m.datecreated    
FROM datatype dt inner join
    data d on dt.datatypeid = d.datatypeid inner join
    mytable m on d.mytableid = m.mytableid
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this structure is optimal for what you want, but if you are stuck with it....

something like this might help.(i have not tested it at all)

My assumptions

- there is some sort of predicate...just not listed
- not every id has 2 addresses, therefore they would be eliminated if you did an inner join
- the mytable serves some purpose, i just don't see why it is here from the example.
- datatype table has more values than address1 and address2

  ```
  WITH address1 as (
  SELECT id,datavalue
  FROM data
  WHERE datatypeid = <datatypeid for addr1>
  ),
  address2 as(
  SELECT id,datavalue
  FROM data
  WHERE datatypeid = <datatypeid for addr2>
  )
  SELECT d.id,
  a1.datavalue as address1,
  a2.datavalue as address2
  FROM data d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN address1 a1 
  ON d.id = a1.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN address2 a2
  ON d.id = a2.id
  ```

again, you <strike>might</strike> will have to do some tweaking to the sql, because it would not perform in a production environment with a lot of rows

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand well what's the structure of your database but I can help with my suggestion:

```
SELECT     B.id
FROM       datatype A INNER JOIN
                      data B ON datatype.DataTypeID = data.DataTypeID INNER JOIN
                      mytable C ON data.ID = mytable.ID
```

This helps to be sure that there's no conflict between attributes.

RQ: You have put `data.ID` with ID (uppercase) in `INNER JOIN` and in `SELECT` you have put in lowercase. This may cause the problem, I'm not sure.

Comment: see my edi for table structure

Comment: your request is always unclear, try to more clarify your needs.

Comment: `So i want to make a select statement to show the ids from mytable and address1, address2 etc as columns, with the values coming from data.values as follow:` not clear enough